# Блок с позицией fixed при маленькой ширине экрана.

Tags: html, css

Всем привет!

Проблема, вроде бы, достаточно стандартная, но никак не могу решить.

Есть сайдбар (шириной 200px), он прикреплен к верху экрана и находится слева (свойство left не задано). И все хорошо, до тех пор, пока щирина экрана >= ширине страницы. Как только страница не влезает в экран, появляется горизонтальная прокрутка. И если двигать ползунок в лево, менюшка налезает на контент.

**Пара скриншотов:**

В нормальном положении:

[image: В нормальном положении]

Прокрутили:

[image: Прокрутили]

Ближе к вечеру (если не решу проблему) залью на фиддл.

**UPD**: Ах, да, забыл сказать, из-за чего весь сыр-бор: я хочу обойтись без глобального изменения макета и, по возможности, без JS.

Comment: на то он и fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/alpha9000/dbTbh/

```js
$(document).scroll(function() {
  k = $(this).scrollLeft();
  $('#nofix').css('left', -k);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="nofix" style='position: fixed; left:0; width:200px;'>{menu}</div>
<div style='width:1000px; height:1000px; margin-left: 200px; border-left: 1px solid #777'>{content}</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте, а если сделать пробел там. Объясняю. Когда мы задаем `position: fixed|absolute;` Грубо говоря мы налаживаем слой. Тогда на первом слое сделаем блок пустой, чтобы занимал место. Вот пример как я вижу это:

```
<div style='float: left; width:200px;'> &nbsp;</div>
<div> {content} </div>
<div style='position: fixed; left:0; width:200px;'> {menu}</div>
```

Comment: Там есть пробел. Проблема в том, что при горизонтальном скроле меню выходит за этот пробел: http://jsfiddle.net/atSL9/ — надпись «меню» налезает на «контент»